# Negative Binomial regression manually

Tags: r, regression, glm

I want to do a Negative Binomial regression manually and define a function that can be used for estimation of an arbitrary number of coefficients. I have

How can I get a matrix of betas and p-values and don't have to write every beta explicity.

For poisson regression I was succesfull as see the below code:

```
daten<-warpbreaks
LogLike <- function(y,x, par) {
  beta <- par
  lambda <- exp(beta%*%t(x))
  LL <- -sum(dpois(y, lambda, log = TRUE))
  return(LL)
}


PoisMod<-function(formula, data){
  form <- formula(formula)
  model <- model.frame(formula, data = data)
  x <- model.matrix(formula,data = data)
  y <- model.response(model)
  par <- rep(0,ncol(x))
  erg <- list(optim(par=par,fn=LogLike,x=x,y=y)$par)
  return(erg)
}

PoisMod(breaks~wool+tension, as.data.frame(daten))
glm(breaks~wool+tension, family = "poisson", data = as.data.frame(daten))
```

In case of Negative Binomial, how to write this part

```
daten<-warpbreaks
    LogLike <- function(y,x, par) {
      beta <- par
      lambda <- exp(beta%*%t(x))
      LL <- -sum(dpois(y, lambda, log = TRUE))
      return(LL)
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the pmf of the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)? Also, you seem to be missing something near the start of your post.

Comment: @mickey,I can define pmf of  negative binomial distribution easily. I have main issue like in poisson "lambda <- exp(beta%*%t(x))", how to write this step in case  when distribution is negative binomial.

Comment: It depends on how you want to parameterize the distribution, but you could do something like the logistic link function `p = 1/(1 + exp(-beta %*% t(x)))`. This will map your regressors to the unit interval. There are two parameters to the negative binomial, so you'll have to deal with the other somehow.